# How to run the this code for Magento 2.3 version

Tags: magento2, error, install-script

I run the following code in magento2.3 but it's showing  Class \Mastering\Itdesire\Setup\Mastering\Itdesire\Setup\InstallData does not exist error.

Content of **InstallData.php**:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of InstallData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 1'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 2'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better that you add code for the file `\Mastering\Itdesire\Setup\Mastering\Itdesire\Setup\InstallData`

Comment: i added already in mastring\itdesire\setup\installdata file stils it show error

Comment: No, I mean, add your file code in your question. here

Comment: and can you help how i run this code in admin of  magento2.3 version

Comment: Can you post the file content?

Comment: ok but how we add the file i don't know can you tell?

Comment: Copy the content from the file and paste it here in the editor inside {}

Comment: i send it the code in the answer you can check and help

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328512/93547(code)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code for your **InstallData.php** file:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of InstallData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 1'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 2'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of InstallData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 1'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->insert(
            $setup->getTable('mastering_itdesire_item'),
            [
                'name' => 'Item 2'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**This is the code**

Comment: this is code anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

You have used the namespace 2 times in your file. like this:

```
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;

/**
 * Description of InstallData
 *
 * @author pramod
 */
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;
```

Just remove last namespace and it will work fine

just use first line of namespace

```
namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Setup;
```

Hope it will help you